# transverse column to rows like matrix in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have scenario like

```
Account_Number | Ins1     |Ins2  | Ins3
8923647324     | 3        | 1    |  5
128736244      | 5        | 2    |  6
9238475323     | 6        | 3    |  7
```

I wanted to achieve something like

```
8923647324     | 3     
8923647324     | 1      
8923647324     | 5
128736244      | 5
128736244      | 2
128736244      | 6
```

It can be done using `UNION`. But looking for some inbuilt feature, which won't affect performance of data retrieval. And, I don't have any clue. Anyone help me on this.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: `sql server 2008` updated tag as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

Using `UNION`

```
SELECT  Account_Number,
        Ins1 AS Ins
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  Account_Number,
        Ins2
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  Account_Number,
        Ins3
FROM YourTable
```

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  t.Accoun_Number,
        x.Ins
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.Ins1),
        (t.Ins2),
        (t.Ins3)
) x (Ins);
```

I would add one way using `UNPIVOT`, but I'll leave that for you to research.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT Account_Number, Ins
FROM tbl
UNPIVOT
(
    Ins FOR Val IN (Ins1, Ins2, Ins3)   
) as unp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Account_Number, Ins1 as Value from mytable 
UNION ALL
select Account_Number, Ins2 as Value from mytable
UNION ALL
select Account_Number, Ins3 as Value from mytable
```